# Using document.createTextNode for text and HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, editor, rich-text-editor

I'm using [`bootstrap-wysiwyg editor(mindmup)`](http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/). In that editor tool, i'm using custom dropdown which contains template names. The templates would be text and some were html. The javascript function for dropdown as follows

```
function loadTemplate(templateId) {
$.post('/Template/GetTemplateDetails', { id: templateId }, function (data, textStatus) {
    if (textStatus == "success") {            
        insertTextAtCursor(data.PreFilledText);
    }       
}, "json"); }
```

insertTextAtCursor function code as follows

```
function insertTextAtCursor(text) {
var sel, range, html;
if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        range.deleteContents();
        range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(text));
    }
} else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    document.selection.createRange().text = text;
} }
```

My question is, If template were html code, then "insertTextAtCursor" function returns raw html, but it works fine for text. When I use `$('#editor').html(data.PreFilledText);` instead of `insertTextAtCursor(data.PreFilledText);` inside loadTemplate function it works fine, but i can't select another template at my cursor point.

So, anyone help me to customize the "insertTextAtCursor" function that uses document.createTextNode to allow both text and html in editor textarea or Is there some other option?